# Group BY serial number and select latest (last) created date for that record

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp-1.3, greatest-n-per-group

I have 1 table column id,serail_no,created.

My display something like this

```
id  serail_no    created

1   1142B00072   2012-11-05 11:36:00
2   1142B00072   2012-12-20 14:57:54 
3   1142B00072   2012-12-28 13:20:54

4   1142B11134   2012-11-25 14:57:54  
5   1142B11134   2013-01-16 16:42:34
```

So now i want output like this .

```
3   1142B00072   2012-12-28 13:20:54
5   1142B11134   2013-01-16 16:42:34
```

Comment: @Catcall , i have upload my query. maybe now you can help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use subquery to get the latest records for every `serial_no`. The result of the subquery is then join back on the original table so you can get the other columns.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT serial_no, MAX(created) max_date
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP BY serial_no
        ) b ON a.serial_no = b.serial_no AND
                a.created = b.max_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b295c/1)

Comment: thanks for help , but now i want to add one more functionality in this query. i have serial_no_days (30,60,90) , how can i find days left between current date and created date according to (30,60,90 )?

Comment: i have attached screen shot in que , maybe now u can solve my prob. your help would be appriciated. there you can see days_left column , first expired , second 4 days remaning , third 49 days remaining to expire license. so i want find record which between 1 to 5 days. but according to latest date.

Comment: @DevangRathod why add a condition on `WHERE` clause so you can filter out your desired result. example `WHERE a.DaysLeft BETWEEN 1 AND 5`

Comment: i m still not understand can u please explain me more. how i put this DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL license_days DAY),CURDATE()) AS days_left in query. because days_left column is not in database. its based on created , license_days and current date.

Comment: can u please re-write query for me so i can understand.

Comment: what happens if you executed the query on the fiddle? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b295c/2 just uncomment the where clause and update the columns in the tableName

Comment: Ohhhh thank u so much , that's working your genius i m really thank full to u sir.if any problem i will let u know.

Comment: Now i have other table like companies,users, which associated to license table , and want fetch information from that table because in license table i have user_id,company_id. so how can i add this table in query and make it combine.

Comment: The current query looks like this `SELECT ... FROM a INNER JOIN (...) b ON a=b WHERE...` just add join after the subquery example, `SELECT ... FROM a INNER JOIN (...) b ON a=b INNER JOIN users ON ... INNER JOIN companies ON ....WHERE...`

Comment: i have tried but i dont know how to do because i dont know much about JOIN query. please help me.

Comment: Ya, now u can see whole table structure i have update in question.

Comment: how are the tables related with `licenses` table? what are the linking column?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23620/discussion-between-jw-and-devang-rathod)

Comment: i'm guessing that they are related with column `serial_no`, see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b295c/4

Comment: table are related with eachother by id. and i have also created association between each table.

Comment: Column name company_id,individual_system_serial_number_id,user_id

Comment: i m approx the end of prob , so please if help me.

Comment: r u there ? i need your help sir.

Answer (score -1):

one more solution: Use rank  function

```
select * from (with t as 
(select 1 id , '1142B00072'  as serail_no ,to_date('2012-11-05 11:36:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') created from dual
union all 
select 2  id , '1142B00072'   as serail_no ,to_date('2012-12-20 14:57:54' ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') created from dual
union all
select 3  id , '1142B00072'   as serail_no ,to_date('2012-12-28 13:20:54','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') created from dual
union all
select 4  id , '1142B11134'   as serail_no ,to_date('2012-11-25 14:57:54'  ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') created from dual
union all
select 5  id , '1142B11134'  as serail_no ,to_date('2013-01-16 16:42:34','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') created from dual)
select id,serail_no,created,rank() over ( partition by SERAIL_NO order by created desc ) rn from t)
where rn=1`
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support common table expressions. It also doesn't support windowing functions.